# why acess key and secert acess key failed in javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I created a AWS account for connecting my web page . I have 2 java script function to run the AWS dynamoDB .

i can connect the DB via direct accessKeyId and secretAccessKey . like this code

```
(function() {

// Setup basic AWS configuration
  AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-west-2",
    accessKeyId: "MY_ACESS_KEY",
    secretAccessKey: "MY_SECRET_KEY",
    logger: console
  });

 // Setup some service objects
  var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

  function write_to_db(Wyear,Wsports,Wname){
      var year = Wyear;
      var sports = Wsports;
      var name = Wname;
     //setting write parameters
     var params = {
        TableName :"table",
        Item:{
            "year": year,
            "sports": sports,
            "name": name
        }
    };


    //writting data 
    docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        }
    });
  }

 function read_from_db(Ryear,Rsports){

    var year = Ryear;
    var sports = Rsports;

    var params = {
        TableName: "table",
        Key:{
            "year": year
        }
    };

    docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "GetItem succeeded: " + "\n" + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
        }
    });

 }

 function read_from_db(Ryear,Rsports){

    var year = Ryear;
    var sports = Rsports;

    var params = {
        TableName: "table",
        Key:{
            "year": year
        }
    };

    docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "GetItem succeeded: " + "\n" + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
        }
    });

 }


})();
```

but when i put a another JavaScript with

```
appInfo = {
  db: {
    region: 'us-west-2',
    tableName: 'sports_table',
    readCredentials: {
      accessKeyId: 'key',
      secretAccessKey: 'key'
    }
  }
};
```

and access via

```
AWS.config.update({
    region: appInfo.db.region,
    credentials: appInfo.db.readCredentials,
    logger: console
  });

 // Setup some service objects
  var dbReader = new AWS.DynamoDB({params: {TableName: appInfo.db.tableName}});
```

Now it is not getting connected . Any mistake ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: `Any mistake ? Any suggestions ?` any errors from some log only you have access to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an instance of [AWS.Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Credentials.html) and use it:

```
var credentials = new AWS.Credentials(
  appInfo.db.readCredentials.accessKeyId, 
  appInfo.db.readCredentials.secretAccessKey, 
  null);
```